# How to distinguish Windows Phone 8.1 from Windows 8.1 in WinRT-apps (Javascript, C#)?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone

How to distinguish Windows Phone 8.1 from Windows 8.1 in WinRT-apps using Javascript or C#? I need to know the operating system at runtime. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in code please try using pragma preprocessor.
for example

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE 
  windows phone code here
#else if WINDOWS
 windows 8 code here
#endif
```